# Object doesn't recognized, how to solve?

Tags: c#, class, object, getter-setter

I have a simple code to work with getters and setters. I have created a object from book class in another class. But this object doesn't recognize by the class. Why is that? I get this error

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

```
class Book
{
    private int num;

    public void setNum(int no)
    {
        this.num = no;
    }      
    public int getNum()
    {
        return this.num;
    }


}

class Program
{
    Book bb = new Book();
    public static void Main()
    {
        bb.setNum(10);
        Console.WriteLine("Insert value" + bb.getNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `bb.getNum` -> `bb.getNum()`

Comment: You don't write getters and setters in C# like that. `public int Num { get; set; }` is the idiomatic property.

Comment: In short, you can't directly access `bb` from within `Main()` because `Main()` is static and `bb` is not.  Did you mean to make `bb` static as well?

Comment: `Main` is a static method.  That means that it doesn't apply to any specific instance of `Program`  `bb` is a non-static field, and requires an instance

Comment: @UnholySheep, It's not the problem. The object 'bb' creates the problem

Comment: It's still wrong, even if it's not the main issue

Comment: @Joe it _will be_ a problem after the OP gets over the static/instance problem

Comment: @David and Sam I am, Yeah it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GetNum` is a function, you have to add `()` to it to get the value.

If you don't do this, C# is looking for a property with this name and this does not exist.

Comment: Through true that is not the main issue here and not the reason for the compilation error